# How often to update products from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, caching, storekit

I'm implementing in-app purchase on iOS, and my requirements are that **before** I display the view where people can buy the product, I should understand (when possible) the product's meta-data (primarily local price & title). This is so the view is snappy to load, an can be read offline - even if a user cannot do the purchase itself offline.

To implement this I want to cache our in-app product data in memory (no need for disk cache for now), so even if the device goes offline, as long as the app has not been hard-closed after a successful request was made, I will still have the data.

I also want to update the data periodically (even without a force quit) as it will change over time.

My planned solution currently is to:
- Make a new SKProductsRequest to retrieve data every time the app becomes active, if a successful request has not been made in the past 24hrs.

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone with experience of trying to accomplish a similar requirement have advice / suggestions on this approach?
2. My reason for restricting the update to once every 24hrs is to save network requests / battery for the user. But does anyone know if StoreKit itself handles this for me, i.e. has an internal cache that won't actually make the request too often? (in which case I can just make the request every time the app becomes active, and my solution becomes simpler)